# Change background color in PNotify

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, pnotify

I am using a theme, Porto Admin Theme; http://preview.oklerthemes.com/porto-admin/3.0.0/ui-elements-notifications.html

This theme is using PNotify to deliver notifications: https://sciactive.com/pnotify/

I want to make the notifications in this light pastel color scheme when you select "Bootstrap 4" (or Bootstrap 3) on the Pnotify link listed above, instead of the dark ugly colors. How can I do this?

```
    function notify (message, type){
    new PNotify({
        title: false,
        text: message,
        type: type,
        addclass: 'ui-pnotify-no-icon',
        icon: false,
        buttons: {
                sticker: false
            }
    });
}
```

There is my code

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question is rather specific to this theme which makes it harder to get an answer. The styling can be found in CSS, apparently on the ui-pnotify-no-icon class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS:

```
    /* Alert Success Color */
.custom-notification-alert-success .notification {
    color: #155724;
    background-color: #d4edda;
    border-color: #c3e6cb;
}

.custom-notification-alert-success .ui-pnotify .notification .ui-pnotify-icon > span {
    border-color: #c3e6cb;
}

/* Alert Danger Color */
.custom-notification-alert-danger .notification {
    color: #721c24;
    background-color: #f8d7da;
    border-color: #f5c6cb;
}

.custom-notification-alert-danger .ui-pnotify .notification .ui-pnotify-icon > span {
    border-color: #f5c6cb;
}

/* Alert Warning Color */
.custom-notification-alert-warning .notification {
    color: #856404;
    background-color: #fff3cd;
    border-color: #ffeeba;
}

.custom-notification-alert-warning .ui-pnotify .notification .ui-pnotify-icon > span {
    border-color: #ffeeba;
}

/* Alert Info Color */
.custom-notification-alert-info .notification {
    color: #0c5460;
    background-color: #d1ecf1;
    border-color: #bee5eb;
}

.custom-notification-alert-info .ui-pnotify .notification .ui-pnotify-icon > span {
    border-color: #bee5eb;
}

/* Alert light Color */
.custom-notification-alert-light .notification {
    color: #818182;
    background-color: #fefefe;
    border-color: #fdfdfe;
}

.custom-notification-alert-light .ui-pnotify .notification .ui-pnotify-icon > span {
    border-color: #fdfdfe;
}

/* Alert dark Color */
.custom-notification-alert-dark .notification {
    color: #1b1e21;
    background-color: #d6d8d9;
    border-color: #c6c8ca;
}

.custom-notification-alert-dark .ui-pnotify .notification .ui-pnotify-icon > span {
    border-color: #c6c8ca;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
    function notify (message, type){
    new PNotify({
        title: false,
        text: message,
        type: type,
        addclass: 'custom-notification-alert-success ui-pnotify-no-icon',
        icon: false,
        buttons: {
            sticker: false
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function notify(message, type, class){
    new PNotify({
        title: false,
        text: message,
        type: type,
        addclass: class,
        icon: false,
        buttons: {
                sticker: false
            }
    });
}
```

Then call `notify('Your message','custom', 'your-css-class');`

Comment: I don't want it to be a custom class, I want it to use the default alert classes outlined in bootstrap. Like the demo on their site.

Comment: Look the examples on http://portotheme.com/html/porto-admin/2.2.0/ui-elements-notifications.html and the script on http://portotheme.com/html/porto-admin/2.2.0/js/examples/examples.notifications.js